# MYSQL REGEXP not working when keyword is enclosed in double quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, collation

If mytable.text has the keyword as "keyword" (with quotes) the regex is not able to find it.

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `mytable`.`Text` 
REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', 'keyword', '[[:>:]]'))
```

I see that in DB the keyword is saved as: â€œkeywordâ€

The column properties are LONGTEXT  latin1_swedish_ci.

I want to be able to use word boundaries, but with the exception of double quotes.

Comment: have you tried to change the collation to utf8 ?

Comment: is it safe? Live production DB here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is incorrect data in the database, and not the query.  â€œkeywordâ€ is not "keyword", change 'â€œ' to a normal quote symbol, and it will work. Look at the fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/674b3/1

Both records: without quotes and with quotes were selected from the database.